# Matlab calculate reflection of Vector

Tags: performance, matlab, vector, specular, phong

I have to calculate the Specular Highlights (phong) of an Image. the normal Vector and the "light vector" are given. Now I have to calculate the light reflection - is there an efficient matlab function to flip the light Vector over the normal vector to get the reflected-light-vector?

I<sub>spec</sub> = k<sub>s</sub> * I * (r * v)<sup>p</sup>

Where:
`l` is the light vector
`n` is the normal vector of surface
`r` is the reflection vector
`v` is the vector from reflection point to viewer
`p` is the shininess

Comment: Is it a different reflection than using `a(end:-1:1)`?

Comment: Just to be clear: is your problem the same as computing the anelastic bouncing of an object on a planar surface with no gravity? How is the reflecting surface expressed with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve this mathematically:

Let `N` be the normal vector. 
Let `V` be the light vector.
Let `O` be the reflected vector.

1. `O` is in the same plane as `N`,`V`
2. The cosine of the angle between `V` and `N` is the same as the cosine of the angle between `V` and `O` (With a minus sign).
3. `O` has the same same length as `V`

This yields 3 equations:

1. dot(O,  cross(N,V)) = 0
2. dot(N,V)/ norm(N) / norm(V) = - dot(N,O) / norm(N) / norm(O)
3. norm(O) = norm(V)

After manipulating these equations, you will reach a 3x3 equations system. All that is left is to solve it.

---

**Edit** My colleague has just told me of an easier way:

`V` can be separated into 2 parts, `V = Vp + Vn`

1. `Vp` - parallel to `N`
2. `Vn` - has straight angle with `N`

`O` has the same parallel part `Vp`, but exactly the opposite `Vn`

Thus, `O = Vp - Vn`, but `V = Vp + Vn` and then `O = V - 2 * Vn`
Where `Vn = dot(V,N) * N` (Assuming that `N` has norm of 1)

So the final answer is:

```
 function O = FindReflected(V,N)
     N = N / norm(N);
     O = V - 2 * dot(V,N) * N;
 end
```

**Edit 2**
I've just found a much better explanation on `Math.stackexchange`:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector

Comment: I have theta (the cos angle between n and l and n and O (r) - I have the angle, the normal Vector and the light vector, isn't there an easier way?